# How do I rename the last entity framework migration applied on the database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have created a code -first entity framework migration and applied to the database, is there a way I can rename this migration ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You cannot rename after applying a migration to Database. But you can delete and add another migration with same name or other name.

First reset the migration to last migration

```
  PM>  update-database -TargetMigration:{lastmigrationname}
```

If this is the first migration then

```
  PM>  update-database -TargetMigration:0
```

Delete the existing migration and relevant files from the source code

Add the migration using the name you want

```
 PM>  add-migration {MigrationName}
```

Then update the database with new migration created

```
 PM> update-database {MigrationName}
```